# How to input in pdf forms with pdf-tools?

Tags: pdf-tools

I'm able to click a pdf form's field, input into the minibuffer and finish with `C-c C-c` yet I don't see that input in the pdf after doing nor after saving and re-opening the pdf.

Am I missing something in the upper steps?

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of fillable forms in any pdf-tools doc I could find (and as @dalanicolai's answer mentions, there is apparently no such support currently), so my question was: were you just guessing that you could do that or did you find some information about it somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: Guessing indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF-tools uses the `epdfinfo` server which uses the [poppler library](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) for handling the pdf's. That server does not support forms.

You can click the form fields because they are interpreted as annotations (try `M-: (pdf-annot-getannots)` of the type 'widget', and therefore you can add contents to those annotations.

If you add 'widget' to `pdf-annot-list-listed-types` as follows:
`(add-to-list 'pdf-annot-list-listed-types 'widget)`, then they will also get listed when doing `M-x pdf-annot-list-annotations`.

Poppler is able to handle forms, so for someone who knows C well, it probably should not be too hard to extend the epdfinfo server with forms support. But, because of the many good free alternatives, I guess it has no priority at all.